# DFSR Backlog Stuck on Non-Existent Folders

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage, dfs-r

I have two 2008r2 servers setup in a full-mesh multipurpose replication group. (01 and 02). 01 was the source server. The initial sync just finished last night and there are 2 folders that do not appear on either server but they are stuck in the backlog of changes being pushed from 02 to 01. The backlog from 01 to 02 is clear and is replicating perfectly.

1. I've attempted rebooting 02, this did nothing.
2. The Event viewer for both servers contains nothing helpful.
3. I've attempted creating and deleting the "batman" folder hoping that would clear it out. It didn't. When I created it on 01 it pushed it to 02. When I created it on 02 it created a redundant entry on the backlog.
4. There were some other random files stuck in the backlog. They were unnecessary so I just deleted them from 01 and it cleared them from the backlog. I was hoping to just do the same with the folders...

[image]

Is there somewhere else I can look to help find why those folders are stuck?

Edit:

I also found this from the DFSR debug log (This occurred while the initial sync was finishing up last night):

```
20140513 23:27:39.254 2372 CSMG  6769 ContentSetManager::Initialize csId:{2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB} csName:Art rootPath:E:\Art state:InitialSync(Sync) ptr:0000000000F83D50
20140513 23:27:39.254 2372 CSMG  5547 ContentSetManager::CheckContentSetState Updating content set record csId:{2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB} csName:Art ghosted:0 readOnly:0 readOnlySince:16010101 00:00:00.000
20140513 23:27:39.254 2372 CSMG  5590 ContentSetManager::CheckContentSetState Content set csId:{2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB} state:InitialSync(Cleanup)
20140513 23:27:39.395 2372 STAG  2594 Staging::ScanStagingDirectory Staging space usage is: 285794033664
20140513 23:27:39.395 2372 CSMG  2960 ContentSetManager::StartInitialSyncCleanup csId:{2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB}
20140513 23:27:39.395  448 ISYN   153 InitialSyncCleanupTask::Run csId:{2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB}
20140513 23:27:45.760  448 ISYN   453 InitialSyncCleanupTask::MoveOut Moving \\.\E:\Art\Artist Files\Christine\batman to pre-existing:0x9000000156B80 csId:{2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB}
20140513 23:27:45.776  448 CSMG   547 ContentSetManager::DeleteChildren LDB Updating ID Record:
+   fid                             0x1000000001DF2
+   usn                             0x0
+   uidVisible                      0
+   filtered                        0
+   journalWrapped                  0
+   slowRecoverCheck                0
+   pendingTombstone                1
+   internalUpdate                  0
+   dirtyShutdownMismatch           0
+   meetInstallUpdate               0
+   meetReanimated                  0
+   recUpdateTime                   20140505 11:56:12.179 GMT
+   present                         1
+   nameConflict                    0
+   attributes                      0x10
+   ghostedHeader                   0
+   data                            0
+   gvsn                            {BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
+   uid                             {BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
+   parent                          {29CFABC2-0180-41C7-A9CE-21DD92783892}-v6880183
+   fence                           Initial Sync (1)
+   clockDecrementedInDirtyShutdown 0
+   clock                           20140501 00:01:02.367 GMT (0x1cf64d070b1522c)
+   createTime                      20140124 09:37:42.441 GMT
+   csId                            {2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB}
+   hash                            00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000
+   similarity                      00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000
+   name                            batman
+   
20140513 23:27:45.776  448 LDBX  4435 Ldb::InsertWalkerJob Inserting dirWalkerJob:uid:{BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133 moveType:MoveOut (2) at time:20140514 03:27:45.776
20140513 23:27:45.807  448 DIRW   647 DirWalkerTask::QueueMoveoutJob Queueing move-out uid:{BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133 fid:0x1000000001DF2
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 DIRW   317 DirWalkerTask::Run Start walking directory.
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 DIRW  1373 DirWalkerTask::MoveoutStep Starting to process move-out job. uid:{BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 DIRW  1398 DirWalkerTask::MoveoutStep Iterating children of uid: {BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 DIRW  2764 DirWalkerTask::TombstoneOrDelete LDB Updating ID Record:
+   fid                             0x1000000001DF2
+   usn                             0x0
+   uidVisible                      0
+   filtered                        0
+   journalWrapped                  0
+   slowRecoverCheck                0
+   pendingTombstone                0
+   internalUpdate                  0
+   dirtyShutdownMismatch           0
+   meetInstallUpdate               0
+   meetReanimated                  0
+   recUpdateTime                   20140505 11:56:12.179 GMT
+   present                         0
+   nameConflict                    1
+   attributes                      0x10
+   ghostedHeader                   0
+   data                            0
+   gvsn                            {BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1376267
+   uid                             {BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
+   parent                          {29CFABC2-0180-41C7-A9CE-21DD92783892}-v6880183
+   fence                           Default (3)
+   clockDecrementedInDirtyShutdown 0
+   clock                           20140514 03:27:45.776 GMT (0x1cf6f247911f746)
+   createTime                      20140124 09:37:42.441 GMT
+   csId                            {2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB}
+   hash                            00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000
+   similarity                      00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000
+   name                            batman
+   
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 DIRW   101 DirWalkerTask::Job::Finish MoveOut csId:{2D9CF1D7-50E2-4B3E-AC6B-3D60C6B026EB} uid:{BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 DIRW   893 DirWalkerTask::RemoveJob Removing job type:2 uid:{BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 LDBX  4472 Ldb::DeleteWalkerJob Deleting dirWalkerJob. uid:{BE36C74B-B5FC-4E8A-8735-039CF9FB3982}-v1264133
20140513 23:27:45.807 2372 DIRW   364 DirWalkerTask::Run Exit.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly stale question but have you explored the 'Staging' and 'Conflict and Deleted' folders?

[DFS Staging and Conflict and Deleted Folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782648(v=ws.10).aspx)

One way that you could end up with this situation is the presence of leftover files or fragments floating around in these folders that are not getting properly resolved.  You could clean out those locations to manually 'reset' synchronization on both sides.  However, I'd also investigate the source of the folder and ensure that:

1. Conflicting permissions are not being set on the files/folders in question.
2. Another server or endpoint is not repeatedly creating this folder because of an old or misconfigured script or synchronization task.